# Prolog: eliminate repetitions in query

Tags: prolog

I've been trying to write a simple code, that would behave in this manner:

```
| ?- hasCoppiesOf(X,[a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b]).
X = [a,b] ? ;
X = [a,b,a,b] ? ;
X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;
```

And

```
| ?- hasCoppiesOf([a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b], X).    
X = [] ? ;    
X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;    
X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;    
X = ...
```

This desire resulted in next piece of code:

```
hasCoppiesOf(A,[]).


hasCoppiesOf([H1|T1], [H1|T2]) :-
  append(T1, [H1], X),
  hasCoppiesOf([H1|T1], X, T2).


hasCoppiesOf(A, A, B) :-
  hasCoppiesOf(A, B).

hasCoppiesOf(A, [H1|T1], [H1|T2]) :-
  append(T1, [H1], X),
  hasCoppiesOf(A, X, T2).
```

And it gives me what I want on the second query, however, the first results in:

```
?- hasCoppiesOf(X,[a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b]).
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
```

It seems to be working fine, but that repetition of the same answers bothers me. It's, probably, a simple mistake, but is there a way to make the output prettier? 
And honestly, that a mystery, why Prolog treats two identical arrays as different answers.
Or maybe it's just something wrong with my system?

Edit: 
The gentle guidance of the person in the comments helped me to solve this issue. However, if this question will be reading the person who wants to solve exactly the same problem - code not really working well, my apologies.

Comment: The first thing to look at is whether a given result can satisfy your logic in more than one way. If so, Prolog will show you each success path whether the result is the same or not. If you adjust your logic so that successes are mutually exclusive, that will get rid of most of not all of the redundant results.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm talking about in my first comment. Your first `hasCoppiesOf/3` predicate head is `hasCoppiesOf(A, A, B)`. Any instantiations of `A` and `B` that are non-empty lists will also match `hasCoppiesOf(A, [H1|T1], [H1|T2])`. This could lead to redundant success paths.

Comment: Could you explain in words what `hasCoppiesOf` actually means or does? I'm struggling with your examples. Why does `X=[]` have copies of `[a,b,a,b,a,b]`? It doesn't appear to me that it does.

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of names. I wanted to have hasCoppiesOf/2 which is true when its first argument is a non-empty list and its second argument is a list consisting of zero or more appended copies of the first argument.

Comment: Your first two comments actually helped to solve a problem I've been asking about. However, now it's clear, that my code isn't working). And forcing the first condition to be an array, thanks!

Comment: I've added a solution which does not use `append/3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just made your predicate more complex than it needs to be, probably just overthinking it. A given solution may succeed in multiple paths through the logic.

You can do this without `append/3` by aligning the front end of the lists and keep the original list to "reset" on repeats:

```
% Empty list base cases
dups_list([], []).
dups_list([_|_], []).

% Main predicate, calling aux predicate
dups_list(L, Ls) :-
    dups_list(L, L, Ls).

% Recursive auxiliary predicate
dups_list([], [_|_], []).
dups_list([], [X|Xs], [X|Ls]) :-
    dups_list(Xs, [X|Xs], Ls).
dups_list([X|Xs], L, [X|Ls]) :-
    dups_list(Xs, L, Ls).
```

Here are some results:

```
| ?- dups_list(X,[a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b]).

X = [a,b] ? a

X = [a,b,a,b]

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b]

no
| ?- dups_list([a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b], X).

X = [] ? ;

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ?
...
| ?- dups_list(A, B).

A = []
B = [] ? ;

A = [_|_]
B = [] ? ;

A = [C]
B = [C] ? ;

A = [C]
B = [C,C] ? ;

A = [C,D]
B = [C,D] ? ;

A = [C]
B = [C,C,C] ? ;

A = [C,D,E]
B = [C,D,E] ? ;
...
```

There may be a way to simplify the solution just a bit more, but I haven't played with it enough to determine if that's the case.

Comment: You just rescued me from the week-long suffering. Thanks! That's a piece of elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying for...

```
coppies(Z,Z,[]).
coppies(X,Z,[Y|Ys]):- \+member(Y,Z),coppies(X,[Y|Z],Ys).
coppies(X,Z,[Y|Ys]):- member(Y,Z),coppies(X,Z,Ys).


copies(M,[Y|Ys]):-coppies(M,[],[Y|Ys]).
```

Input:

> copies(X,[1,2,1,2,1,2]).

Output:

> X = [2, 1].

BTW I've used some different names instead..

Comment: I'd like it to output: `X=[1,2]; X=[1,2,1,2]...` and so on. And it seems to be not working with `member()`

Comment: So, got the solution but you are getting answers repeated right? Check the another answer i've posted for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got your problem, you want to eliminate the repetitions.

```
hasCoppiesOf(A,[]).


hasCoppiesOf([H1|T1], [H1|T2]) :-
  append(T1, [H1], X),
  hasCoppiesOf([H1|T1], X, T2).


hasCoppiesOf(A, A, B) :-
  hasCoppiesOf(A, B),!. %Change here, place a cut after the termination.

hasCoppiesOf(A, [H1|T1], [H1|T2]) :-
  append(T1, [H1], X),
  hasCoppiesOf(A, X, T2).
```

This is the change that you need to make.

> ```
> hasCoppiesOf(A, A, B) :-
>       hasCoppiesOf(A, B),!.
> ```

A Cut '!' terminates the unwanted backtracking and thereby repetitions.

Comment: A cut is not generally the best way to fix a problem with redundant logic. The logic should be adjusted to be mutually exclusive. Otherwise, the predicate loses generality. In other words, there can be cases where the cut is actually eliminating valid solutions.